# Who gets the money if a player randoms and swaps their hero?

Tags: dota-2

When you random someone and trade with someone who hasn't randomed, who gets the extra money from the randoming?

When someone on my team has randomed and then wanted to trade, they often say to random and trade. I'm not sure if they just don't care who they get OR if you get the money the person you're trading with has.

Comment: They say to random because they don't care what they get (after all, they randomed the first time). But if you random, you also get extra gold, so the total extra gold per team remains the same even though they lose 100.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When trading heroes only the hero is swapped not the gold. That said you don't get to keep all the money;

When you random you get 200 extra starting gold for a total of 825 gold. If you then swap with someone else it will cost you 100 gold leaving you with 725 gold.

Swapping a hero you picked doesn't cost you any gold so the other player will still have 625 gold.

Comment: Wait swapping costs 100 gold for the swapper? I did not know this

Comment: Only if you random-ed your hero! If you don't it's free.

Comment: @TMP it prevents abuse like randoming > ask someone to pick your favourite hero > buy 825 gold worth of items (since youll keep them after the swap) > swap your randomed hero with your favourite hero > benefit from 200 extra gold worth of items at the begining. You can only get 100 extra gold and add a random hero to your team which makes it less attractive of a technique